# Apply a look ahead in regex that should be followed by the specified pattern and give a match other wise a no match

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

Hello i am new to regex , i needed to apply a regex to a string of us zip codes , which we got from concatenating rows of pandas columns

for example zip being header of the column

```
zip
you have some thing
70456
90876
78905
```

we get the string `zip you have some thing 70456 90876 78905` as single literal string which should be matched by the regex that has some characters followed by one or more 5 digits separated by empty space
so i wrote a simple regex of `'.*zip.*(\d{5}|\s)*'`  a zip followed by any number of 5 digit characters   but it gives a match(re.fullmatch) **zip 123456** a zip which is followed by a 6 digit code

for that reason i thought of using look ahead assertion in regex, but i am not able to know how to use it exactly it not giving any matches , i used look behind with re.search also but it also seems to fail , can some one give a regex having word zip and also only a 5 digit characters at the end may be a nan

here are the codes i have written

`re.match('(?=zip)(\d{5}|\s)*','zip 123456')`

```
<re.Match object; span=(0, 0), match=''>
```

`re.search('(?<=zip)(\d{5}|\s)*','zip 123456')`

```
<re.Match object; span=(3, 9), match=' 12345'>
```

can some one tell me how to write a regex for  **if** .*zip.* follwed by digits having only 5 digits give a *match* **else** *None*

`re.match('(?=zip)(\d{5}|\s)*','zip 123456')`
`re.search('(?<=zip)(\d{5}|\s)*','zip 123456')`

those are the codes i have tried i need a regex having any alphanumeric charcters that contain zip followed by a  5 digit numeric code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```py
re.search(r'\bzip\b\D*\d{5}(?:\s+\d{5})*\b', text)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TuITLG/3). If you want to also capture the ZIPs, you can use a capturing group:

```py
re.search(r'\bzip\b\D*(\d{5}(?:\s+\d{5})*)\b', text)
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TuITLG/5).

*Details*:

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `zip` - a `zip` string
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `\D*` - zero or more chars other than digits as many as possible
- `\d{5}` - five digits
- `(?:\s+\d{5})*` - zero or more sequences of one or more whitespaces and then five digits
- `\b` - a word boundary

Comment: it gave no output or match in jupyter notebook for zip 12345

Comment: @i-1 I can't see your code, but I am sure [mine works well](https://ideone.com/wKeVBA).

Comment: `re.search('\bzip\b.*?(\d{5}(?:\s+\d{5})*)\b','zip 12345 56789')` it gave nothing in jupyter notebook

Comment: @i-1 You see, you are not using MY code. You missed the raw string literal `r` prefix.

Comment: yeah got it, but it is working for six digit too `re.search(r'\bzip\b.*?(\d{5}(?:\s+\d{5})*)\b','zip 123456 56789')` here is output `<re.Match object; span=(0, 16), match='zip 123456 56789'>`

Comment: @i-1 Then a clarification is needed: can there be other digits btween the `zip` and the 5-digit sequences? If not, see the updated solution.

Comment: yes you may , but it will be followed like charcters like 10 dollars, something like that a english text, it is difficult i know , could you give me if there are  no digits between zip and 5 digits

Comment: @i-1 Yes, see the above answer and if you find cases where it does not work, I will update.

Comment: Thank you, where can i know more about word boundary

Comment: @i-1 A canonical resource would be [Word Boundaries](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html). There are numerous SO posts about word boundaries, too.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using word-boundary (`\b`) as follows

```
import re
t1 = 'zip 1234' # less than 5, should not match
t2 = 'zip 12345'  # should match
t3 = 'zip 123456'  # more than 5, should not match
pattern = r'zip\s\d{5}\b'
print(re.search(pattern, t1))  # None
print(re.search(pattern, t2))  # <re.Match object; span=(0, 9), match='zip 12345'>
print(re.search(pattern, t3))  # None
```

`\b` is zero-length assertion useful to make sure you have complete word rather than just part. See [`re` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) for details of `\b` operations.

Comment: i need more than one 5 digit, for example `zip 12345 23451` and also zip may have `zip zzzz  12345 23451`